# Displaying Decimal places of a floating point in C

Tags: c, decimal, point, floating, divide

Here i have some simple code, used to calculate speed given a distance and time.

Since we have a division, a float variable is required, however, in my program below, it won't display correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int NewDR=0;
float NewSR=0;
int NewTR=0;


int main()
{ 
    printf("What is your new distance?");
    scanf("%d",&NewDR);

    printf("What is your new time?");
    scanf("%d",&NewTR);

    //NewSR = NewDR/NewTR;
    NewSR = (float)NewDR/(float)NewTR; //-Fix is here, thanks

    printf("Speed: %.2f",NewSR);

    getch();
}
```

Input:

```
Distance: 20
Time: 3
```

Expected output:

```
Speed = 6.67
```

Actual output :

```
Speed = 6.00
```

Answer (score 3):

In `NewDR/NewTR` , since both the operands is an integer,an integer division is performed which yields an integer(in your case, 20/3=6) and is then assigned to `NEWSR`. For performing a floating point division,just cast any one of the variables into a `float` like this:

```
NewSR =(float) NewDR/NewTR;
```

Answer (score 1):

change `NewSR = NewDR/NewTR;` to `NewSR = ((float)NewDR)/((float)NewTR);`

Before arithmatic operation, you need to have either of the operands in `float`, otherwise, the operation will take place as `int`s and the final result will be promoted to `float` [based on the target storage data type.]

Answer (score 0):

Integer Number divided by Integer results in Integer. More Over you Need to Type-Caste it Explicitly. Implicit Conversion happens only when you are using from higher the Hierarchy to lower hierarchy (Ex: from flot->int).

Hence use `NewSR = (double) NewDR/NewTR;`

It will work out for you.